# How to generate a R wrapper for a C function that returns an int*?

Tags: c, r, swig

I would like to generate a R (programming language) wrapper for the following C function:

```
int *test(void)
{
    int i;

    i = 1024;

    return (int *) i;
}
```

To create this wrapper I am using SWIG with the following interface:

```
%module X
%{
    extern int *test(void);
%}
extern int *test(void);
```

I can successfully create and compile this wrapper. However, when I run the following R code (the wrapper was loaded beforehand):

```
print(test())
```

It will give the following error:

```
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “_p_int” is not a defined class
Calls: print -> test -> new -> getClass
```

My question is the following: how can I wrap the C `test` function (more precisely the `int *` returned by this function)?

Answer (score 0):

SWIG is not so widely used around R.  But the [inline](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=inline) package can help you.

```
R> library(inline)
R> foo <- cfunction(signature(i="int"), body="*i = 1024;",
+                   language="C", convention=".C")
R> foo(12)$i
[1] 1024
R>
```

That said, you probably want `.Call()` instead of `.C()`, and you should probably look into [Rcpp](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=Rcpp) even if you want to use plain C -- the tooling is pretty rich and useful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Dirk. What about in SWIG?

Comment: Did you read the first sentence I wrote?  I don't know, and I doubt many others do.  I have used it once or twice in the distant past, but these local-to-R packages are more performant _for R_ use.